# Inserting multiple records in a form

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel, foreach, controller

I am trying to insert several records at once from a form
[This is how the form appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fxNO.png)

```
     <label>Drug</label>
        <select class="form-inline input-sm " name="drug[]" id="drug">
             @foreach($drugs as $key => $drug)
                    <option value="{{$drug->id}}"> {{$drug->name}}</option>
             @endforeach
         </select>

      <input class="input-sm" type="number" class="form-control" id="amount_received" name="amount_received[]" placeholder="Amount received">

      <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add More</button>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"id="submit">Submit</button>
```

My controller

```
public function addNewStock()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $insert = array();
    foreach($input['drug'] as $key => $drug) {
        $insert[$key]['drug'] = $drug;
    }
    foreach($input['amount_received'] as $item => $amount_received) {
        $insert[$item]['amount_received'] = $amount_received;
    }
    Stock::insert($insert);

}
```

This is the result i get when i dd($input). This is after i submit two record, problem is it picks the last record and saves i twice in the database

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "Oz9cSvNuPmPPHKAw6uKbnmA5DIMBsxKsnubaliHt"
  "drug" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
1 => "10"
  ]
  "amount_received" => array:2 [▼
0 => "2"
1 => "4"
  ]
]
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you `dd($input)` and post in your question?

Comment: Did as you asked, thanks